# how to access website located on windows server from client?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, vmware, windows-server-2012, lan

I have a windows server (2016) that working as a domain controller (active directory), and I have IIS enabled with one website (ASP MVC web application).

I have a client (windows 10 via NAT vmware) with administration permission, how can I get access to the website (that located on the server).

Configs are like the following:

```
windows server:
ip:192.168.183.132
default gateway:192.168.183.2
dns server:   ::1
              192.168.183.2

Client (windows 10):
ip:192.168.183.128
default gateway:192.168.183.2
dns server:192.168.183.2
```

**the website working well in the windows server browser, but not accessible by its clients.**
is there any problem with my configuration?

Comment: How do you access from local? IIS might not be listening on network adapter per configuration.

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone I am accessing through the domain (administrator user), I mean my windows 10 client is domain based.

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone is there any way to make it listening on the network adapter, or is there any other solution ?

Comment: Only a guess, I'm from linux. This might contain helpful information https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/954874/iis-binds-to-all-ip-addresses-on-a-server-when-you-install-iis-7-0-on

Comment: At least you could gather more information and add this to your question.

Comment: As written, it would be hard for anyone here to do config/debug for you. Add more info. You were asked "how you are trying to access"? Is it by IP, or by some name? If the latter, there is an assumption that you have some naming system (DNS) _configured properly_ - if so do `nslookup` to verify. In either case, what's the error, if any? Can you `ping` the server?

Comment: https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html Can you check the site bindings?

Answer (score 0):

Removing Median DNS IP, changing the client's dns server to the server ip solved the problem.

> Client (windows 10): ip:192.168.183.128 default gateway:192.168.183.2
>   dns server:192.168.183.132